# How calc angle of sectors by two points, radius, center of circle

Tags: math, geometry, sector

How calc angle of sectors by two points, radius, center of circle.
I try this: (p1,p2 - points in circle, center - center of circle)

```
startAngle = (int)(180 / Mathf.PI * Mathf.Atan2(p1.y - center.y, p1.x - center.x));
endAngle = (int)(180 / Mathf.PI * Mathf.Atan2(p2.y - center.y, p2.x - center.x));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks good to me, assuming you want to measure the angles in degrees anticlockwise about the x axis.

[Here it is in Latex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67ZyM.gif), with the subscript zero quantities being the centre of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can find angle between vectors to the first point and to the second point using cross product and scalar product. This approach gives signed (directed) angle.

```
dy1 = p1.y - center.y;
dx1 = p1.x - center.x;
dy2 = p2.y - center.y;
dx2 = p2.x - center.x;
SectorAngle = Mathf.Atan2(dx1*dy2-dx2*dy1, dx1*dx2+dy1*dy2)
```